# Select max ID en PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, mvc, codeigniter-3

me encuentro haciendo una simulación de un sistema en codeigniter la cual trabaja en con MVC. Estoy intentando pasar el **ultimo ID** de mi tabla **"usuarios"** a un campo llamado **"usuario_id**" de mi tabla **"clientes"** (Ya que están relacionadas con un FK) y todo para que desde un formulario *para registrar un Cliente que se le asignara el ultimo Usuario registrado*. Para ello eh intentado hacer lo siguiente:

En mi controlador:

```
public function registro_cliente(){
        $id_usuario = $this->Clientes_model->lastID(); //llamada a mi modelo
        $nombre = $this->input->post("nombre"); //es el que paso en el formulario
    }

$data = array('usuario_id' => $id_usuario,
              'nombre' => $nombre );
}
```

Y en el modelo tengo lo siguiente:

```
public function lastID(){
    $this->db->select_max("id_usuarios");
    $this->db->where("borrado", "1");
    $this->db->from("usuarios");
    $resultados = $this->db->get();
    return $resultados->result(); }
```

Pero el resultado de eso **me arroja un ARRAY** y sale lo siguiente:

> Message: Array to string conversion || solo noto que en la inserción dice ARRAY (Pero obviamente no insertaría eso, por eso el aviso de error)

También lo eh intentado con lo siguiente:

```
public function lastID(){
    $this->db->select_max('id_usuarios');
    $this->db->from('usuarios');
    $query=$this->db->get()->row(); }
```

y arroja lo siguiente:

> Column 'usuario_id' cannot be null || Nuevamente (mas abajo del error) arroja el NULL como lo que se intentaba insertar.

Y eh estado intentando otras muchas formas pero sin un resultado en concreto, eh buscado y tampoco nada. Necesito ayuda, por favor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba imprimiendo con print_r la variable $id_usuario en el controlador para que veas su estructura. El return del modelo no es un string, sino un array con un object dentro y el problema se genera en esta parte del codigo:

```
 $data = array('usuario_id' => $id_usuario, 'nombre' => $nombre );
```

Puedes acceder al valor de la columna id_usuarios de la siguiente forma en el controlador

```
 $id_usuario = $this->Clientes_model->lastID(); //llamada a tu modelo
 echo ($id_usuario[0]->id_usuarios); // este si deberia ser un string
```

te recomiendo que pruebes imprimiendo con print_r la variable $id_usuario para que comprendas mejor.

Espero sea de ayuda mi respuesta :)

Comment: Mil gracias, me has salvado :D Efectivamente es así, lo hice como me dijo y vi de una forma atendible lo que me estaba devolviendo, aplique la linea para obtener solo el ID que me dijo y por ultimo solo lo asigne esto a una nueva variable y todo LISTO! De verdad, GRACIAS!!